# Descuento en java

Tags: java

Buenas estoy creando una aplicacion en la que el cliente elige una serie de productos con su precio, pero quiero que cuando se le de al boton descuento el total sea un 10% menos y sino se preta ningun boton me salga el total a pagar sin ningun tipo de descuento mi codigo es el siguiente, espero que podais ayudarme gracias de ante mano.

```
 public void imprimirRecibo() {

 double total1 = 0;
    if(productos.getBtnDescuento().getActionListeners().equals(this)){
        total1 += total-((total/100)*10);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se imprime el recibo. El total ha pagar es " + total1 + " €");

    }else{
    int totalRow = tabla.getRowCount();


    for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) {
        total = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tabla.getValueAt(i, 0)));
        total1 += total;

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se imprime el recibo. El total ha pagar es " + total1 + " €");
}
```

Comment: Puedes especificar el problema con el que te has encontrado? Errores? Algo que no sepas como se hace?

Comment: ¿Por qué no escribes el código en el ActionListener del botón? Si no, hazte un método y llámale